# oauth: Meteor authentication issue on own server

Tags: oauth, meteor

I'm working on an app the requires a log-in by using oauth mechanisms from LinkedIn, Twitter, Google.
On the common meteor server this authentication method works fine.

However, I recently deployed the meteor server on my own server, and I get an authentication error when I try to log in. I tried linkedin and twitter and receive the same error, so I guess something is wrong on my server.
The error is in a browser window:

---

The requested URL /_oauth/linkedin was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

### Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at exomodal.com Port 80

The meteor server is at port 3000.

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, in Google, it asks for a redirect url and an origin url. During development, you registered these as `localhost:3000/`. But when you deploy, you are not using `localhost` anymore. Update these URLs in your "API console" (That's what they call it in Google) if any exists. As far as I know, Google and Facebook requires some sort of url registered.

Also, API configurations (client/consumer id and secret) are usually stored in the DB. Upon deploy, you don't usually ship your development DB, leaving behind the configurations which were on your development machine. What we did was to hard-code these into the server code, so that every time the server is restarted or redeployed to a "clean server", it inserts those configs to the DB.